# Obtain the MGF of $Y$.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable whose probability density function is:
$f_{X}(x)=e^{-x}$

Then, obtain the Moment Generating of function of $Y=1-e^{-X}$

What I did:

We can find a bound for $y$ using $x$, which gives, $0<y<1$

$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(1-e^{-x}<y)$

$=P(X<-log(1-y))=\int^{-log(1-y)}_0 e^{-x} dx$

$\implies F_Y(y)=y$

Therefore $f(y)=F^{'}(y)=1$

Therefore $M_Y(t)=\int^1_0 e^{ty} \cdot 1 dy =\large \frac{e^{t}-1}{t}$

May someone point out the mistakes, if any?

Also I tried, in a similar way, to obtain $f(y)$ directly using $f(x)$ but I can't do that right? Because probabilty at a particular point is $0$. Am I correct?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. You can do it also directly without finding the distribution of $Y$, i.e.
$$\int e^{-x}e^{(1-e^{-x})t}\mathrm{d}x$$ and consider $a=1-e^{-x}$ and $e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}a$ which will give you $$\int_{0}^1e^{at}\mathrm{d}a=(e^t-1)/t$$